# Manage multiscreen size with TextField Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to design a page for my Flutter app that can be displayed with the same aspect on all screen devices without having to scroll to see the bottom of the page. In the left image below you can see the result of my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline: TextStyle(fontSize: 64.0),
          subhead: TextStyle(fontSize: 48.0),
          title: TextStyle(fontSize: 36.0),
          subtitle: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
          button: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
          body1: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black),
          body2: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/settings');
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Text(
                'My Title Here',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 64.0),
              ),
              TextField(
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
              ),
              TextField(
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
              ),
              RaisedButton(child: Text('Start'), onPressed: () {}),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.star),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.star),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.star),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It's very simple, and it's looking fine, but when I clicked on the second `TextField`, I have a problem of overflow like you can see in the right image : (I made my test on an iPhone 5s).

[image]

I tested to add a `SingleChildScrollView`, a `SafeArea` but when I do that I have a big blank space at the bottom of the screen and it's not what I m looking for. How can I solve this ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is a closed issue on [Flutter repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13339). Replace your column with ListView and instead of using alignment property add paddings and margins to your textfield

OR

You can use `SingleChildScrollView` as you said in the question

Both the cases you need to add padding to textField to fill the blank space

Comment: I found this post too, but this case looks to simple for me to be a bug, I tested these solutions without success.